# Discrete mathematics, is this a function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, relations

Let A={1,2,3,4,5} and B={a, b, c, d}, and let f={(1,a),(2,a),(3,d),(4,c)}
is f a function? , the text book I'm working from says it's since all mapping are one to one or many one to many, & non are many to one, but the element 5 isn't mapped to anything, so is it not a function & the book is wrong?

Comment: You are right. $5$ must have an image for $f$ to be a function. (But maybe the books says something different...)

Answer (score 1):

The book is being subtle.  $A$ and $B$ are just sets.  It does not say they are domains or codomains of the function.

$f=\{(1,a),(2,a),(3,d),(4,c)\}$ is a set of mapping pairs.

It maps a set of values:  $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to a set of values $\{a,b,c,d\} =B$.  And there are no "one to many mappings".   So it is a function $f:\{1,2,3,4\}\to B$.

But it is *not* a function $f:A \to B$ and there is no element $(5,x)$ or $f(5)$ or "$5$ is not mapped".

So you are correct.

I don't know if the book intended this.  I imagine the book actually made an error and you caught it.

But technically $f$ *is* a function; Just not a function with domain $A$.